# django saving form field in generic or functional view

Tags: python, django, view

Lets say I have a form and its files are user, value, age

I am using generic or functional view... so how can I do like

```
def SomeView(request):
    mod = MyModel()
    mod.user = request.user
    mod.value = form.cleaned_data["value"]
    mod.save()
```

I think `mod.value = form.cleaned_data["value"]` can only be done with class based view. But how can I do this in generic or functinal view.

Comment: Did you read the very clear documentation on [using forms in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view)? No class-based views to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it with functional views, you need to check the request.POST

```
def SomeView(request)

    c = RequestContext(request, {})
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = YourForm(request.POST or None  )

        # your code here, 


       # redirect on success probably  
    else :
       # create blank form 
      form = YourForm(None)

    c[form]=form      
    return render_to_response("path/to/your/templet.html", c)
```

Comment: can I use cleaned_data here ??

Comment: yes, where I put "# your code here" - just use the code you posted, the from instance is created with the post data, and the cleaned data can be accessed from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `value` data from request(GET or POST) - `request.GET.get('value', 'default_value')` or `request.POST.get('value', 'default_value')`

Comment: I want to use from form dude.. btw thanx

Comment: Do you want to use form class? Or what?

Comment: yup I want to use form class